# Binary numbers with at most

Tags: combinatorics, binary

I am trying to find how many binary numbers are there with $10$ digits if the first two must be $1$s.

I am thinking this to be $2^{10 - 2}$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks fine to me ... $256$

Answer (score 3):

This is like the same problem as creating a $8$ digit number, then attaching two $1$s in front of it. Therefore, our answer is: $$2^8=\boxed{256}$$

Comment: The word is "therefore"; "therefor" has a different meaning.